macOS Parallels firewall configuration to manage guest?
I use Parallels to run different type of OS (Windows, Linux) on the macOS ARM64. I would like to improve the overall security of the machine to be able to connect to a LAN or Wifi and still have a good handle over what is going in and out of the guest VM.
I have tried different approach, I realized that VPN client inside the guest create some type of issues, same when the VPN is in the Host. Overall I don't think that is the ideal option on macOS/parallels. I have tried to install linux firewall as guest however Parallels does not seems to let me use two network card at the same time on one VM; which is required for instance for PFire.
I haven't tried paid application directly installed on the host, I presume that is the only option left? In that regard, do you have any recommendation of a solution that could be installed as a desktop software but act as a firewall for the network ? I could pass the IP of the host as the default gateway and use bridge config in Parallels to have the guest vm appears as separate machine of the LAN. I know it is probably a bit of a stretch but I am hoping to avoid having to carry a box for a hardware firewall (I understand how much this would be better).
